# IE11 javascript not working and developer console blank

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, internet-explorer-11

weird problem on one of our servers w2k12. Users reported one internet website showing wrong and I found out it's because JavaScript just does not want to run in this browser on any websites. It's the same version as on other servers - 11.0.9600.18894. Putting website into trusted sites does not help. Security settings for all zones have Scripting / active scripting: Enable.
If I press F12 the dev console is weirdly blank, so I suppose something fails to load. [image]

Reboot did not help, there is nothing in eventlog and checkdisk did not find anything. Will try sfc /scannow yet...

Comment: Do you use an AV that block script ?

Comment: There is Kaspersky but it's on other servers as well and disabling it did not help.
SFC Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations

Answer (score 0):

If the Dev console is blank you have an error that isn't letting the page load at all
It is probably not a security setting and someone changed something that screwed up the javascript
you should try disabling scripts one at a time to see who the culprit is and once you find it fix the error

Hope this helps

Comment: sorry, I am not sure what you mean. The page loads but parts of it are missing and I tested on other browsers that it happens when scripting is disabled. I made a test page with one javascript command alert("dfgsdgf") and it does not do anything in IE on this server while on others it displays a messagebox, so scripting just does not work at all.

Comment: http://help.elecosoft.com/powerproject_bim/english/14.0.03/
it is this webpage. With scripting disabled the contents blocks are empty. You can test for yourself. With FireFox Portable it works. Only in IE I can't get it to work on this one server.

Comment: That is very odd, on my Internet Explorer it works just fine. You might have to add some legacy JS code that will run on your older version of IE.  Im guessing your JS version is too updated to work with that older version of IE. You could post the code so we could see.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? your Jquery is version v1.12.4 
You should look up if that version is compatible with the IE you are using

Comment: sorry but what older version are you talking about? I clearly said all IEs are the same version. There is no older one. The version number is in my first post. And how would I add a legacy js code onto a public website?

Comment: Internet Explorer version I meant. I looked at your link and saw it is running Jquery v1.12.4 and wanted to make sure the browser you were using to access it was compatible
Not sure what you mean about adding legacy js code onto a public website, if you own the website just go to the folder where the js is located on the server and modify it there.
you can look up depreciated js code on this website or others.

Comment: spacesamurai please just read the OP. I say IE is version 11.0.9600.18894 which is the same as on all other servers where this website works. And no we don't own this website so cannot change any JQuery in it. Anyway so far it seems customer forgot about it or stopped caring...